# Wildcards for preg_match

Tags: php

If a user enters in the text input with the id "my_input" the words "sun", "moon" or "stars", the script does stuff.

How should my script look in order to use wildcards? Ex: If the users enters "The stars are bright", the script still does stuff...

```
if(preg_match("/^(sun|moon|stars)$/i", $_POST['my_input']) === 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildcard for regex is `.*`

```
if(preg_match("/.*(sun|moon|stars).*$/i", $_POST['my_input']) === 1) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Tested here [phpliveregex.com](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/75m)

Comment: Thank you! But now the script executes "// do stuuf" even in the user enters "The starsssssss are bright"... I need to match "stars" exactly...

Comment: Ok.. I should add \b before and after the word... Thank you!